# Coding minecraft client, crash on startup (MCP)

Tags: java, client, minecraft, nosuchmethoderror

What I get when I open the game  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgcjf.png

I'm trying to code a minecraft client, and for some reason it will not start up. I'm using ModCoderPack 1.12 version,
details:

Crash report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vHN8WPqjqQ/

DxDiag: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zwDn3tqggw/

Let me know if there's any more information you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `shadersmod.client.Shaders` class was compiled with Java 9 or newer but you're trying to run it under Java 8. Minecraft 1.12 doesn't support running under Java 9 or newer, so your only solution is to recompile it with Java 8.